# How to mainain log file in java

Tags: java, logfile

I want to store(append) output of my java code after every execution in the same file. Like including the SOP statements, execution time , no of files executed etc.

Comment: you want help with appending to a file or to get execution time and other details please be clear .

Comment: check here : https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/util/logging/write-log-entries-to-log-file/

Comment: I want to store all the above things in a single file. Like every time the program is executed all the details should be stored in the same file.

Comment: @NikhilTalaviya Thanks for the link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
try(FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("outfilename", true);
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(bw))
{
    out.println("the text"); // appends text
    //more code
    out.println("more text"); // appends text
    //more code, append more text etc.

} catch (IOException e) {
    //exception handling left as an exercise for the reader
}
```